# Is "as" used correctly in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, syntactic-analysis, conjunctions

> Young, naive and trusting as I was, I
>   believed every lying word he said.

From what I learned, "as" used the way here should mean "though". But if it means "though", the meaning of this sentence is wrong, and a correct sentence should be:

> Young, naive and trusting as I was, I
>   didn't believe a single lying word he said.

or

> As I was young, naive and trusting, I
>   believed every lying word he said.

Is my understanding right?

Comment: Nope, *as* doesn't mean *though* here. The sentence roughly means "I believed every lying word he said *because* I was young, naive and trusting".

Comment: @RegDwight: Please see my response below. I had to make it an answer because it involved too much formatting.

Comment: It is funny that the need to apologize for making answers should be felt. I know the feeling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading through all the discussions, I think one of @RegDwight's comments address the problem most accutely. "As" is used in the sense of comparison here, as indicated by one entry of New Oxford American Dictionary:

> 2 used to indicate by comparison the
>   way that something happens or is done
>   : dress as you would if you were
>   having guests | they can do as they
>   wish.

But "as" could mean "though":

> 4 even though : sweet as he is, he doesn't pay his bills | try as he might, he failed to pull it off.

You can see, in fact, the form "as" is used in my sample sentence is a perfect example of this "even though" usage.

However, one interesting fact of English is that sometimes one has to reverse-engineer the usage of a word in a sentence from the acceptable meaning of the sentence, although generally one determines the meaning of a sentence from the usage of the constituent words.

Answer (score 3):

I happen to differ slightly with @RegDwight & @JSBangs on this point.

I believe "as" does not *necessarily* mean "because" in this context (although it might). I believe it can also be used in the second sense my Webster's gives, which is

> 2 during the time of being (the thing
>   specified) : he had often been sick as
>   a child | as a student, my nickname
>   was Space.

So in that respect I believe it could mean that "by comparison to the way I am now (that is, older and wiser), I believed every lying word he said."

I think of the beginning of Dylan Thomas' poem "Fern Hill":

```
Now as I was young and easy under the apple boughs
     About the lilting house and happy as the grass was green,
       The night above the dingle starry,
         Time let me hail and climb
       Golden in the heydays of his eyes
```

It is clear that what follows indicates a comparison to a later state, not a causal relationship. That is, the narrator of the poem is at a time of life when he is no longer so "golden" as before. The person who believed the lying bastard may mean the same kind of comparison.

Again, let me stress that I'm not saying that *as* can't or doesn't mean *because* in the OP's example; I'm merely pointing out that it may also mean something a little different.

Comment: Hold on a sec. At no point did I mean to say that *as* means *because* here. What nonsense that would be. I only said that a) it doesn't mean *though*, and b) the sentence, as a whole, roughly means "I believed [...] because I was [...]". I still mandate that. But it has nothing to do with *as* — as can be demonstrated by dropping the "as I was" part completely: "Young, naive and trusting, I believed every lying word he said". I thought that was pretty obvious, but then again I do see how my half-assed comment could be misleading, so apologies for that.

Comment: I will also add that I don't think that *as* is used here in the meaning "during, when", either. To me, it simply means "to the same degree or amount", as in "As young, naive and trusting as I was...". It's only in the sentence "As I was young, naive and trusting..." that *as* might actually mean *because* or *when*. However, "As I was young, naive and trusting..." is not the same as "Young, naive and trusting as I was...".

Comment: It is a reasonable interpretation, except that "as" in the meaning you gave is a preposition instead of conjunction. I'm inclined to agree with @RegDwight's comment above.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is correct as written. *As* is used with the sense of *because* in this sentence, and is placed before the subject of the subordinate clause as a type of literary inversion. As RegDwight said in the comments, the sentence means "I believed every lying word he said because I was young, naive and trusting".